# Can't navigate to a nested DrawerNavigator route in react-navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am trying out react navigation, but I seem to be having trouble with navigating to a nested DrawerNavigator route within my react native app.

After a successful login action, I would like to navigate to the Home screen but it doesn’t work

My setup looks like the following;

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator, addNavigationHelpers } from                 'react-navigation';
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers';
import AppNavigator from './AppNavigator';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                state: this.props.nav,
            })} />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    nav: state.nav
});

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);

class Root extends Component {
    render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {},     applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

        return (
            <Provider store={ store }>
                <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <AppWithNavigationState />
                </View>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default Root;
```

NavReducer.js

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import AppNavigator from '../AppNavigator';

const initialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
    NavigationActions.init()
    // AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main')
);

export default navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

    // Simply return the original `state` if `nextState` is null or undefined.
    return nextState || state;
};
```

AppNavigator.js

```
import { StackNavigator, DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage';
import LoginScreen from "./components/LoginForm";
import RegistrationScreen from "./components/RegistrationForm";
import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";

const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
    LandingPage: { screen: LandingPage },
    Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    Registration: { screen: RegistrationScreen },
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'LandingPage'
});

const DrawerNavigatorStack = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: { screen: Homepage }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
});

const DrawerNavigation = StackNavigator({
    DrawerStack: { screen: DrawerNavigatorStack }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'DrawerStack'
});

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    LoginStack: { screen: LoginStack },
    Main: { screen: DrawerNavigation }
}, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    initialRouteName: 'LoginStack'
});

export default AppNavigator;
```

Login action

```
export const loginUser = ({ email, password }) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER });
        const data = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        };

        const url = Globals.API_URL + 'accounts/login';
        return fetch(url, data)
            .then(response => {
                const responseBody = JSON.parse(response._bodyText);

                if (response.status === 200) {
                    dispatch({ type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS });

                    dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
                        routeName: ‘Home’,    <=== supposed to navigate to the Home screen at this point
                        params: responseBody.data.access_token
                    }));
                } else {
                    loginUserFail(dispatch, responseBody.message);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

It successfully dispatches the LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS and the subsequent Navigation actions, but it doesn’t actually navigate to the Home screen

If I replace the ‘Home’ route with a route from the ‘LoginStack’ it will navigate to that screen with no problem. So for example, this would work

```
dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: ‘LandingPage’,    <=== will successfully navigate back to the LandingPage
    params: responseBody.data.access_token
}));
```

I’m obviously missing something, any ideas what that might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try navigating to `Main`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I get similar behavior, but this exception is also being thrown `TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.` Haven't been able to figure out why yet